# Flood-fill and Bresenham corner

Tags: drawing, flood-fill, bresenham

I'm trying to fill shapes which I have rendered using [Bresenham line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) algorithm.

Unfortunately I cannot make flood fill reach tight corners from inside of shapes. Is there any way to handle such scenarios?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZty.png]

Only solutions which I could came up is having thicker lines and using 8 directions flood fill. Which is not optimal. And having more than one starting point for fill flood algorithm which will decrease performance.